# scrollbars are hidden and the page content is not completely shown

Tags: html, css

Im facing two problems which are related with each other as i can assume. My webpage is not being fully displayed, a lot of content is hidden down and the scrollbar at the right side and the vertical one are not shown. I have tried to solve that with the overflow property in the body, the scrollbar was there but invisible so it didnt help me a lot. I want the content to be visible even though im zooming in(200% or whatever)

here is a snippet of my code

```
<nav class="sideBar">
        <div class="sideBarHeader" id="wrapper">
            <div class="dropdown">
            </div>
            <div class="ono">
                <p style="font-size: 48px;">XXX</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-left: 2px;">
            <div class="searchContainer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="mainContentClient">
        <div class="clientHeader">
        </div>
        <div class="clientContent"> <!-- the client content class is not defined yet -->
            <table class="onoTable paddedManagementTableContent thUpperCase">
                <tr>
                    <th style="height: 40px;"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #DEDEDE; height: 100px;">
                    <td style="border-bottom: 0;">STATS</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="height: 100%;" id="wrapper"> <!-- subcontent -->
                <!-- left tables -->
                <div class="leftClientContent">
                    <table class="onoTable paddedManagementTableContent thUpperCase">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="height: 40px;">
                                <a href="vehicle/">
                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="onoTable paddedManagementTableContent thUpperCase">
                        <tr>        
                            <th style="height: 40px;">
                                <a href="cargounit/">
                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- right table + Map -->
                <div class="rightClientContent">
                    <table class="onoTable paddedManagementTableContent thUpperCase">
                        <tr>        
                            <th style="height: 40px;" colspan="2">
                                info
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 10%;"></td>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 90%;"><input type="text" placeholder="" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 10%;"></td>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 90%;"><input type="text" placeholder="" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 10%;"></td>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 90%;"><input type="text" placeholder="" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 10%;"></td>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 90%;"><input type="text" placeholder="" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 10%;"></td>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 90%;"><input type="text" placeholder="" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 10%;"></td>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 90%;"><input type="text" placeholder="" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 10%;"></td>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0; width: 90%;"><input type="text" placeholder="" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="onoTable paddedManagementTableContent thUpperCase">
                        <tr>        
                            <th style="height: 40px;">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: 0;"> <!-- map properties -->
                                <div id="Map" class="mapStyling"></div>
                                <script>
                                    var lat            = 47.35387;
                                    var lon            = 8.43609;
                                    var zoom           = 18;

                                    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   
                                    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); 
                                    var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

                                    map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
                                    var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
                                    map.addLayer(mapnik);

                                    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
                                    map.addLayer(markers);
                                    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));

                                    map.setCenter(position, zoom);
                                </script>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css :

```
.sideBar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 17%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.sideBarHeader {
    padding: 4% 8%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    height: 85px;
}
.clientHeader {
    font-size: 48px;
    height: 130px;
}
.mainContentClient {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 77%;
    margin: 0 280px;
}
.ono {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: right;
    /* keep the ono aligned, use a negativ margin*/
    margin-top: -28%;
}
.clientContent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1130px;
    max-width: 1500px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
.leftClientContent {
    width: calc(100% - 850px);
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.rightClientContent {
    width: 850px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.mapStyling {
    width: 102.5%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
/* default settings for the tables in part management*/
table.onoTable{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table.onoTable th {
    background-color: #FBD85C;
    border-width: 0 10px;
    border-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 62.5px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
table.onoTable th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table.onoTable th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
table.onoTable td {
    border-width: 0 10px 4px 10px;
    border-color: black #f1f1f1;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
table.onoTable td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table.onoTable td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
/**/
table.noBorder_1_2 td:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: 0;
}
table.noBorder_1_2 td:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 0;
}
table.centerContent_24 th, table.centerContent_24 td {
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 24px;
}
tr.borderBottom_0 > td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.backgroundColor_grey {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

/* shift the content of the main table of the management table a little bit to the right side*/
table.paddedManagementTableContent td {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
table.paddedManagementTableContent th {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width:30%;
}
table.paddedManagementTableContent th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

here is a live demo

https://jsfiddle.net/edwjvmsc/

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this would be correct answer. but I removed the 'position:fixed' property from 'mainContentClient' class and the scrollbar is showing and you can scroll your content. Try it and let me know if it helped :).

```
.mainContentClient {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 77%;
    margin: 0 280px;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this has fixed an issue. Do you know how can i keep the content of the right side to be shown even when i zoom more? because once i zoom the vertical scroll bar appears directly, i have tried max-width inside the mainContentClient class but i cant zoom more than 140% and then the scrollbar appears. Thanks

Comment: Okay I think what you're looking for is responsive web design. You want the content of your website or div to automatically adjust to the size of screen, You can try this guide. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_col-s . Try adjusting the size of the page and you can see it adjust to size of screen. Even when you're zooming. Bootstrap works best for these scenarios to give you responsive design. :)